# Django placing of WHERE in raw SQL query

Tags: sql, django, where-clause, rawsql

The order of the WHERE in this query was wrong, but it is correct now.

```
postModel = list(PostModel.objects.raw(
SELECT max(pub_date), 
   count(topic_id) AS freq, 
   count(DISTINCT author) AS contributors 
   FROM crudapp_postmodel 
   WHERE author = "art" 
   GROUP BY topic_id 
   ORDER BY pub_date DESC
))
```

Thanks

Comment: the WHERE comes after the table name

Comment: You should really read the documentation on creating SQL queries before asking for help, but this should work: `SELECT max(pub_date), count(topic_id) AS freq, count(DISTINCT author) AS contributors FROM crudapp_postmodel WHERE author = "art" GROUP BY topic_id ORDER BY pub_date DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
SELECT max(pub_date), 
       count(topic_id) AS freq, 
       count(DISTINCT author) AS contributors 
       FROM crudapp_postmodel 
       WHERE author = "art" 
       GROUP BY topic_id 
       ORDER BY pub_date DESC
```

Comment: @solarissmoke actually answered it also. Thanks